# Struts2 URL with .action

Tags: java, url-rewriting, struts2, friendly-url

I want the URL of the below format

http://localhost/users/abc

rather than

http://localhost/users?name=abc

How to achieve this in Struts2?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [REST Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html) or the [convention plugin](http://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/convention-plugin.html) (see [this blog post](http://simplyolaf.blogspot.com/2009/06/creating-hierarchical-actions-in-struts.html) for more details on the later solution). Other options include servlet filtering or mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using struts2. All you need to do is, use wildcard characters in your action name. Let me explain with your case

```
http://localhost/users/Santhosh
```

This is what you wanted as the end URL. And you would want to capture the value i.e.; "Santhosh" in action support.

I'm assuming that you're ready to add a struts2 suffix at the end i.e.; ".action" or ".html" (I've customized my action classes extension as .html).

Just define the mapping as below in struts.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
  "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
  <constant name="struts.action.extension" value="html" />
  <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>

  <action name="users/*" class="com.srm.action.UserAction" method="execute">
    <param name="userName">{1}</param>
    <result name="success" type="tiles">addEditCategory</result>
  </action>
</struts>
```

If you observe above mapping, "struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" should be set "true" in order to achieve this.

Here the action support class

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String userName = null;

  public String execute() throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println("Username: "+userName);
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public void setUserName(String userName)
  {
    this.userName = userName;
  }

  public String getUserName()
  {
    return userName;
  }
}
```

After executing this program, you'll get "Santhosh" value populated into userName property.